# Screen freezing with new graphics card!

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I recently bought a new graphics card, a nvidia GeForce gtx 960 OC edition, and have been experiencing random freezes.
As it freezes Ctrl+alt+f2 and ctrl+alt+f7 will NOT work, and I'll have to reboot. I have searched a while online, and all suggestions didn't work. I have tried installing different nvidia drivers, including the one on their website, but unfortunately they did not resolve the issue.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release?

Comment: The ubunru version is 16 LTS